# Are 2k+ Rep users overwriting suggested edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, community-user

**Context:** There have been a few times that I have put quite a bit of work into a suggested edit, only to see an hour later that it shows as **Rejected** since someone else with 2k+ rep has edited the question.  Since their edits don't need to be approved, they immediately took effect and my edit was discarded. The ones I am curious about are the ones that state:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

When there is a pending suggested edit on a post, is the `Edit` button also greyed out for 2k+ rep users and my situation is simply caused by overlapping edit times? Or are they able to edit the post regardless of a pending suggested edit?

Comment: Additionally for the downvotes, some context would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Well, you might want to add the specific rejection-message. Is it "edit-conflict", or "look what you should have done"?

Comment: @Deduplicator Thank you.

Comment: You may also want to change the title so it's clear that you're asking *if* this is happening, not making an accusation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "pending suggested edit".

As far as the system is concerned, a suggested edit is only pending once it has been posted. At that point, no one will be able to edit the post until the suggested edit has either been approved or rejected.

If the expectation is that while someone is writing a suggested edit, all edits to a post are to be blocked, then no, that doesn't (and mostly likely never will) happen.

Comment: Perfect, that is was I suspected I simply just wanted to confirm.  Thank you.  I will accept once it allows me to.  Also when I said pending suggestion edit, I did mean once it was submitted, not while in the process of editing.

Comment: Well, with moderate skill in URL-hacking (or a side-trip through the revision-history), a 2K user can convince the system he started editing before the suggestion was posted, even if he did not. Which allows him to disregard any pending edit, letting the system auto-reject as edit-conflict.

Comment: @Deduplicator This thought had crossed my mind.  Though if a user is desperate enough for edits to go through that much work then they can have them.

Comment: _@Oded_ _"At that point, no one will be able to edit the post "_ That's not entirely true: Besides of _Approve_ and _Reject_ I actually also have the choice to _Improve_, and immediately overwrite the proposed edit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - still, that's can only happen in the *context* of approving/rejecting the suggested edit.

Comment: @Oded But the OP asks _"is the Edit button also greyed out for 2k+ rep users"_. It isn't, but I can still enter via that button, and see the edit review page, that allows me to choose _Improve_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - and as _part_ of that, you select whether to approve or reject the suggested edit.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I am entirely unable to imagine why anyone would bother doing something like that when both "improve edit" and "reject and edit" will accomplish the same thing more easily.

Comment: @Kevin: Well, if you don't want to have it count for nor against someone, that's the only way. Though you are quite right doing so deliberately (meaning hacking the URL) is quite unneccessarily cumbersome, and appropriately rare.